# Display a Calendar from Outlook 2010 with resources in public space

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, exchange-2010

In our current office environment when someone wants to book a meeting room they simply write it down on the paper calendar outside the meeting room.  I want to change it by putting an LCD screen outside the room with a list of all meeting occurring in the month.  We use Exchange 2010 and I already have resources set up with the meeting room names.  What I want is when someone books a room through the meeting request in Exchange is it will publish to this "room" calendar (the LCD screen) for everyone to see and eliminate the paper copy.

The computer to be placed outside the meeting room will simply be a monitor connected to a small computer that only displays the current month.  It should work similar to Google calendar but have the ability to see all meetings booked and show the booking times for that resource (for example, North Meeting Room).

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial systems that do this, and Digital Signage solutions that can integrate with Exchange to pull up calendar information for just this purpose.  In the end, they will use Exchange Web Services to get the calendar info.  This API is well documented and will be pretty much future-proof (as opposed to a legacy protocol like MAPI).

SE doesn't allow recommendations, and I'm not sure I'd recommend any of the products I've seen.  I hope I have given you a bit of background to proceed.

Edit: Similar question, with a technical answer: [Adding exchange room calendars to iPad](https://superuser.com/questions/517814/adding-exchange-room-calendars-to-ipad).  You might opt for an out-of-the-box solution instead.